# How to define routing concern in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to define rails route concern

I have attachment for user and message. how can i defined common route

```
resources :comments
```

Routes for user and message controller

```
resources :users
resources :messages
```

Comment: Common means what you have define like resources :comments and that will create all the possible(7) restful routes for CRUD on comment.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question you have  a attachment for both user and message and need a more DRY way of creating routes for this. We can use concerns for this purpose.

```
concern :attachable do
  resource: :attachment #singular routes
end

resources :users, :messages, concerns: :attachable
```

I have used singular routes as I assume there is a has_one relationship  between attachment and user/message. That is, user has_one attachment or message has_one attachment. If its a has_many relationship, use plural routes ie

`resources: :attachments`

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://thehungrycoder.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-4-routing-concerns.html), you'll need:

```
#config/routes.rb
concern :attachment do
  resources :attachment, only: :index
end

resources :users, :messages, concerns: :attachment
```